# How should I evaluate the numerical integral of a function wich has an divergent part on the denominator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to evaluate (numerically or symbolic) the following integral  in Mathematica:

$$
\int_{0}^1-\frac{2 \pi  r^2 e^{-\frac{1}{4} \delta ^2 k^2 r^2} J_0(k r \rho )}{r^2-1}dr
$$

However, symbolic I am not getting any answers and numerically (using necessary $\delta = 10, \rho=0.1 \quad e \quad k=2\pi/500$) I get:

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {0.999999999999999999999999999983692735662508754221254924558311692180}. NIntegrate obtained 463.96601513939015`and 72.74569744420805` for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: The denominator is Infinity when r=1, thus the straightforward numerical solution does not converge.

Comment: In fact the numerator stays away from zero near $r=1$, while $\int_0^1\frac{dr}{r^2-1}$ diverges, so the integral is $\infty$

Comment: With: `Integrate[(
 2 E^(-k^2 r^2 \[Delta]^2) \[Pi] r^2*(Series[
     BesselJ[0, k r \[Rho]], {r, 0, 1}] // Normal))/(-1 + r^2), {r, 0,
   1}]` we can see that `"Integral does not converge on {0,1}."`.

Comment: This might converge for certain values of `k ρ` for which the Bessel function has a zero for `r=1`